# How to use Ctrl+ c for a QAction shortcut

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I try to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> event to operate a copy action. For this purpose I use QMainWindow and QAction

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
```

I have made a menuBar and add QAction  with "Ctrl + c" shortcut  to it:

```
  def _create_menu(self):

        file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")

        copy_data = QAction(text="&Copy", parent=self)
        #copy_data.setShortcut("Ctrl+c")
        copy_data.setShortcut(Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_C)
        copy_data.triggered.connect(self._on_copy_data)

         file_menu.addAction(copy_data)
```

and
create my function

```
    def _on_copy_data(self):
        self._bits_widget.copy()
```

But when I pressed on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> **_on_copy_data** function didn't trigger and when I use the menu bar and clicked on copy the function is trigger.

also if I change the key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> for example this will work.

Where is my mistake? I use Pyqt5 in Ubuntu OS

Comment: Do you have any text field (QLineEdito, QTextEdit, etc) in your window? If that's so, that's the reason: Ctrl+C is the standard shortcut for copying, and text editors automatically *grab* it, meaning that it will not be propagated to any of their ancestors (parents).

Comment: @musicamante Thnaks, I have some spinbox maybe it is the problem, but how I can to fix it?

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea to change well known keyboard shortcuts that are considered standard convention: overriding ctrl+c in a text control (including a spin box) can be very annoying for people accustomed to keyboard shortcuts, and I would suggest you to think about another keyboard sequence instead (maybe by adding another modifier: ctrl+shift+c).

Comment: if my QWindows has also a widget child then can I to grab the "Ctrl + c" there? how to implement it Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "has also a widget child"? Shortcuts have contexts, which are widget, window or application; if the context is *widget* it only works as soon as the widget has keyboard focus.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @herzlshemuelian Why do you need a menu item for `_bits_widget,copy()`? Why not just add a shortcut to `_bits_widget`? Creating a menu item with a standard shortcut like ctrl+c is a very bad idea, as it will conflict with many other widgets with built-in shortcuts, e.g. spin-box, line-edit, text-edit, etc.